How to compute the start time of all the jobs?
I was recently given this coding question in a mock interview and I couldn't do it. How should you do it?
You are given a connected DAG where each node corresponds to a job. Each job lasts for a positive number of minutes but can't start until the last of its parents has finished. It is also true that any job that has a  parent must start as soon as it can and there should be no gap in time between when a job finishes and the first of its children starts.
If I tell you the start time of one of the jobs, how can you efficiently find the start time of all the other jobs ?  You can assume that all the criteria can be satisfied.
As an example, consider the graph A->C B->C . Let A take 3 minutes and B take 1. If we know that A starts at minute 0 then B must start at minute 2. C starts at minute 3.
I can do a topological sort of the nodes to start with. But I am not sure how to use that to fully answer this problem.

Topological sort.

@user24714692 I thought about using that but I am not sure how to make it work for my problem.

Why should B start at minute 2? What is holding it back from starting at 0?

The problem statement contains no specification of when jobs without parents must start. Should we presume they start at time zero?

@trincot apologies. I edited the question to add that there should be no gap in time between when a job finishes and the first of its children starts.

@EricPostpischi B can't start at 0 between then it would have to wait for 2 minutes before C starts

@Simd, that is a too strong requirement. How would that turn out for a diamond like a->b, a->c, b->d, c->d, where  a, b and d take 1 minute and c two minutes? Should b start at 1 (to be adjacent to a) or at 2 (to be adjacent with d)? It can't be adjacent to both.

@trincot we are allowed to assume all the requirements can be met. So that sort of graph is not allowed.

Given the assumptions that the DAG is a connected graph and where the implied distance between two nodes is uniquely defined, even if there are multiple paths, you could take this approach:

Use depth-first traversal to visit all the descendents of the starting node, determening their start times.

For each node  visited in the previous step, but has at least one nonvisited parent, use a depth-first traversal to determine the start times of all nonvisited ancestor nodes of .

For each node  visited in the previous step, but has at least one nonvisited child, use a depth-first traversal to determine the start times of all nonvisited descendent nodes of .

As long as not all nodes are visited, repeat from step 2.


The order in which edges (either "upward" or "downward") are followed is not relevant as long as edges are only visited once.
So this can also be done with a BFS approach where the nodes on the frontier are expanded one step in both up and down directions to nodes that were not yet visited.
Implementation
Here I will take the BFS approach.
To ease this process, we should make sure we have a graph structure that has for each node the set of its parent nodes and the set of child nodes.
During traversal, we can immediately delete an edge from this graph in both directions once we have traversed it. This way we can be sure to only spend O() time complexity on the whole task.
Here is an example input we could use as a test, provided in JSON format:
{
    "a": { "duration": 5, "children": ["b","d"] },
    "b": { "duration": 4, "children": ["c"]     },
    "c": { "duration": 2, "children": ["p"]     },
    "d": { "duration": 2, "children": ["e","i"] },
    "e": { "duration": 2, "children": ["c"]     },
    "f": { "duration": 1, "children": ["c"]     },
    "g": { "duration": 5, "children": ["f","h"] },
    "h": { "duration": 2, "children": ["o"]     },
    "i": { "duration": 3, "children": []        },
    "j": { "duration": 2, "children": ["g","r"] },
    "k": { "duration": 3, "children": ["e","i"] },
    "l": { "duration": 2, "children": ["k","n"] },
    "m": { "duration": 3, "children": ["k","n"] },
    "n": { "duration": 4, "children": []        },
    "o": { "duration": 3, "children": ["q"]     },
    "p": { "duration": 2, "children": ["q"]     },
    "q": { "duration": 1, "children": []        },
    "r": { "duration": 4, "children": []        }
}

This represents the following job scheme (and solution if we are given one of the start times):

Here is an implementation of the algorithm in JavaScript, which is run for the above input, starting at node "e" for which the start time (7) is given:


// Create a new data structure for the input that includes
// parent references, and represents both children and parents
// as hash sets for efficient processing:
function createGraph(jobs) {
    // O(V): create node for each job
    const graph = {};
    for (const [jobId, job] of Object.entries(jobs)) {
        graph[jobId] = { 
            parentSet: new Set(), 
            childSet: new Set(), 
            start: null,
            duration: job.duration,
        };
    }
    // O(E): populate the sets
    for (const [parentId, job] of Object.entries(jobs)) {
        for (const childId of job.children) {
            graph[childId].parentSet.add(graph[parentId]);
            graph[parentId].childSet.add(graph[childId]);
        }
    }
    return graph;
}

function timeJobs(jobs, jobId, start) {
    const graph = createGraph(jobs);
    const node = graph[jobId];
    
    let frontier = new Set();    
    node.start = start;
    frontier.add(node);

    // BFS: every edge visited once in one direction: O(E)
    while (frontier.size > 0) {
        const newFrontier = new Set();
        for (const node of frontier) { // An already timed job
            for (const child of node.childSet) {
                child.start = node.start + node.duration;
                newFrontier.add(child);
                child.parentSet.delete(node); // Avoid going back
            }
            for (const parent of node.parentSet) {
                parent.start = node.start - parent.duration;
                newFrontier.add(parent);
                parent.childSet.delete(node); // Avoid going back
            }
        }
        frontier = newFrontier;
    }
    // Extract start times
    const result = {};
    for (const [jobId, node] of Object.entries(graph)) {
        result[jobId] = node.start;
    }
    return result;
}

// The example input:
const jobs = {
    a: { duration: 5, children: ["b","d"] },
    b: { duration: 4, children: ["c"]     },
    c: { duration: 2, children: ["p"]     },
    d: { duration: 2, children: ["e","i"] },
    e: { duration: 2, children: ["c"]     },
    f: { duration: 1, children: ["c"]     },
    g: { duration: 5, children: ["f","h"] },
    h: { duration: 2, children: ["o"]     },
    i: { duration: 3, children: []        },
    j: { duration: 2, children: ["g","r"] },
    k: { duration: 3, children: ["e","i"] },
    l: { duration: 2, children: ["k","n"] },
    m: { duration: 3, children: ["k","n"] },
    n: { duration: 4, children: []        },
    o: { duration: 3, children: ["q"]     },
    p: { duration: 2, children: ["q"]     },
    q: { duration: 1, children: []        },
    r: { duration: 4, children: []        },
};

// Run the algorithm
const startTimes = timeJobs(jobs, "e", 7);

// Report on the result
for (const [jobId, start] of Object.entries(startTimes)) {
    console.log(jobId, start);
}




How would this take to run to completion?

With the assumption that the DAG is connected, you would eventually visit all nodes, which is the end-condition.

Any idea of the running time? I feel it should be doable in time proportional to the size of the graph .

As the graph is connected,  >= −1, so we can express the time complexity with just . It should be possible to implement this (using Hash sets/maps) with a time complexity of O().

That would be cool! I would love to see that

Added an implementation.
